# Access to variable from another class objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, variables

How to access instance variable which is defined in class viewController.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    Class1* class1;
}
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController
class1 = [[Class1 alloc]init];
@end
```

Class1.h

```
@interface Class1 : NSObject
{
NSMutableArray* variablesArray;
}
@property NSMutableArray* variablesArray;
```

Class1.m

```
@implementation Class1
@synthesize variablesArray;
@end
```

Now I would like to access to instance "class1" variable "variablesArray" from Class2.m. I want to add and get objects from MutableArray "variablesArray". Is it possible?

Comment: `@implementation ViewController class1 = [[Class1 alloc]init]; @end` is a syntax error, you can't have bare code in an implementation.

Comment: you can access the property of class1 in any other class. Just create an object of class1 in the corresponding class where you want to access that, and call the property as class1object.VariablesArray

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is Possible.

Make object of other class and access the variable.

In claas2 import Class1 (#import "Class1")

```
Class1 *objClass1= [[Class1 alloc] init];
```

now access like

```
[objClass1.variableArray  addObject:@"object"];

[objClass1.variableArray  objectAtIndex:0];
```

If you want to access same instance of array make a Singleton Class 
by adding this class method in your class

```
+ (Class1 *)sharedInstance
{
    static Class1 *shared = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken,
                  ^{
                      shared = [[self alloc] init];
                  });

    return shared;
}
```

and access in Class2 like

```
[[Class1 sharedInstance] variableAray];
```

Comment: When I write: Class1 *objClass1= [[Class1 alloc] init]; Compiler create new instance (objClass1) of Class1, is it true? But I would like to access variable of instance created in ViewController. I don't want to alloc new instance in Class2.m

Comment: @user2374693 it is not the right way. why you do not want to create the object of class1 in your class2? If you want to access the property of a class you do need to create the instance of that class

Comment: @user2374693 we can continue this chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48865/accessing-class-property

Comment: For example I store used random numbers in instance of Class1. Class2 is for finding random number and should add this number to Mutable Array of instance Class1. I can't store numbers in instance allocated in Class2, because when it is allocated, used numbers are rewritten.

Comment: @user2374693 In this case you need to make a Singleton Class. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can access the public property of a class instance by simple using the dot-operator. Notice that there are several ways to encapsulate an instance variable by setting property attributes like (readwrite, readonly).

```
Class1 aClass = [[Class1 alloc] init];
aClass.varibalesArray addObject:@[ @"someObject" ];
```

Make sure you initialize the NSMutableArray correctly in the init method of Class1

```
- (id)init
{  
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _variablesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
  } 
  return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can access variable in another class by Simple making property of the variable like this

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *str;

I gave an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872136/accessing-variables-in-another-class-objective-c/21872145#21872145) close to this please check this link